# How do I test parallelStream().map(interface_impl -> method(interface_impl)0.collect(Collectors.toList()) with Mockito's whens?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, parallel-processing, mockito

So I am creating a unit test utilising Mockito.

A component of the code I'm testing looks like this:

```
public Object validateObject(final Parameter param) {
    Object validated_object = new Object();

    final List<Object> processed_objects = interface_impl_list.parallelStream()
        .map(interface_impl -> parallelTask(interface_impl))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (final Object object : processed_objects) {
        validated_object = object;
        if (Object.getResult == PASSED) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return validated_object;

private Object parallelTask(InterfaceObj interface_impl) {
    return validate_object(interface_impl);
}
```

Our teams 'template' for unit tests would look something like this:

```
@Spy
private List<InterfaceObj> interface_impl_list;

@Mock
private InterfaceImpl1 interface_impl_1;

@Mock
private InterfaceImpl2 interface_impl_2;

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    interface_impl_list.add(interface_impl_1);
    interface_impl_list.add(interface_impl_2);
}

@Test
void myTest() {
    // Variables needed
    final int x = 1

    // Return variables
    ... 
    
    // when()'s
    // Not sure how to do this for parallelStream
    when(interface_impl1.method()).thenReturn(returnVariable1); //i.e. within validateObject()
    when(interface_impl2.method()).thenReturn(returnVariable1);

    // Method being tested
    final Object object = classBeingTested.findWillToGoOn(x);
    
    // verify()'s
    verify(interface_impl1, times(2)).method();
    verify(interface_impl2, times(2)).method();

    // assertions
    ...
}
```

I can't seem to find any examples of someone using whens or general unit testing examples for parallelStream.forEach().map().collect() that I can apply here.

How would I go about this? Is there any examples people could even point to?

Thanks in advance

So the parallelStreams is a recent addition. Previously the code would just call the parallelTask consecutively so I would just add when's in order of when that external class method was called.

I played around with doing when(interface_impl_list.parallelStreams.map().collect(Collectors.toList())) and some variations but I can't get past any intial compile errors and figure out how to go about it.

Edit: Error Message without mocking/adding when for the stream or any of the map or collect methods

`java.lang.NullPointerException at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractTask.compute(AbstractTask.java:327)`

Comment: What do you need to mock about `interface_impl_list.parallelStreams.map().collect(Collectors.toList())`? The only thing you have any choice over there is the function that you pass to `map`.

Comment: So without some sort of when(), I get a `NullPointerException` on the line `.collect(Cellectors.toList())`. So I am trying to mock the behaviour within the `parallelTask()` and functions called within. So I'm unsure in bridging this gap for lack of better words.


For context, I cannot test the private parallelTask() method directly as there is only one public method for the test class

Comment: Not sure why you are needing to mock a stream, parallel or not. It seems you just need need to understand the interactions of your own code i.e. `InterfaceImpl1` and `InterfaceImpl2`. Can you add more of the class you are testing?

Comment: @D-Dᴙum I have added a bit more, the `InterfaceImpl1` and `InterfaceImpl2` will both call a variation of the same method inside validateObject.

I'm currently getting a nullpointer error without adding some sort of when() for the parallelStream

Comment: I'm thinking it's how I've set up my Mock interface implementations and the list.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what is being tested here. There shouldn't be a reason to mock the stream and the mapping functions because they are calling the methods of the mocked object. what is in `classBeingTested.findWillToGoOn(x);` as you've commented that this is the method under test?

Comment: @D-Dᴙum you are right, no reason to mock the stream. The issues I'm have is because of using `@Spy` for my list, afaik it's creating instances of the interface implementations and this led to some unexpected behaviour. Thanks for taking the time to help I appreciate it

Comment: Mocking streams is universally a bad idea.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to mock the parallel stream. Just set value of interface_impl_list in the test class using a setter or `setInternalState`. This will in turn cover those lines for you.